# Rendering NSView in another context

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsview

Im looking for a way to have one `NSView` draw inside another `NSView`, to make a preview of that view. To be exact Im using `VZVirtualMachineView` and want to have a preview only in a grid. I would just use `VZVirtualMachineView` but there is one issue with it - it captures mouse cursor (can hide it) and reacts to clicks and mouse movement over it. And in this case I want to have only the preview with no interaction and no cursor hiding.
So I thought I might try rendering it inside another `NSView` using `vmView.layer?.render(in: context.cgContext)`, or some other similar mechanism.
The question is how to do this properly? And how to make it refresh with correct time? Should I use something like `CADisplayLink`? Do I need to add this view first somewhere or can I draw it without adding? Also I would like to not use something like creating image (unless this would be efficient method)
Here is very simple first try, but Im not happy with that code, so
Please suggest some approaches that I should try.

```
class VMPreview: NSView {
    
    let vmView: VZVirtualMachineView
    var timer: Timer?
    
    init(virtualMachine: VZVirtualMachine) {
        self.vmView = .init()
        self.vmView.virtualMachine = virtualMachine
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        addSubview(self.vmView)
        dr()
    }
    
    func dr() {
        self.setNeedsDisplay(bounds)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.dr()
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override var frame: NSRect {
        didSet {
            self.vmView.frame = bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: bounds.height)
        }
    }
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current else { return }
        vmView.layer?.render(in: context.cgContext)
        self.setNeedsDisplay(bounds)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: If the only issue is the mouse then have you tried disabling the mouse?

Comment: How would I do that? I was trying to find something similar to userInteractionEnabled (from iOS), but couldn't find anything related. Also disabling hitTest is not enough, as cursor still is hidden on top of that view

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSView+disable+mouse